# How to update a subfield element from another subfield element in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Image this data structure :

```
{
_id: 1
 ...
sections: [
 { 
    Title: 'hello world',
    Title2: '',
 },
 {
    Title: 'goodbye',
    Title2: ''
 }
]
}
```

I need to update all Title2 from Title.

I tried things like :

```
db...update(
{  },
[{ $set: 
    { 
        "sections.Title2": "sections.Title",
     }
   }])
```

but without success. Also tried with updateMany and some variants like **sections.$.Title2**.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do via update + aggregation pipleine(mongod 4.2+) & $map as follow:

```
db.collection.update({
  sections: {
    $exists: true
  }
},
[
 {
  $addFields: {
    "sections": {
      $map: {
        input: "$sections",
        as: "s",
        in: {
          "Title": "$$s.Title",
          "Title2": "$$s.Title"
       }
      }
     }
    }
   }
 ],
 {
   multi: true
 })
```

Explained:
Find and replace the existing sections  with mapped the necessary array values for Title2 to Title.
Add the option {multi:true} to update all documents in collection

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jhBiruZznTA)

Improved version2:

```
db.collection.update({
  sections: {
   $exists: true
  }
},
[
 {
   $addFields: {
  "sections": {
    $map: {
      input: "$sections",
      as: "s",
      in: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$$s",
          {
            "Title2": "$$s.Title"
          }
        ]
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
 ],
 {
  multi: true
 })
```

Explained:
In this version you merge the changed value with the subdocument so you dont need to add every of the other fields that are nto going to be changed.

[playground2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zax_RFb2oUM)

Comment: I got one problem with this script. If there is other type of fields in "sections" they will be erased. Do you know how to avoid that ? @R2D2

Comment: One simple option is to  add them as "Field": "$$s.Field"  in the "in" section , there is other options I will check and get back to you later today ...

Comment: Oke , added for you better improved version2 using $mergeObjects  where you dont need to add every of the subfields that do not need to be changed inside the $map